# nginx DNS redirect: how does it work

Tags: http, nginx, deployment, dns

I'm trying to do some DNS redirect: if user access `h##p://subdomain.mydomain.com`, he/she will be redirected to `h##p://www.mydomain.com/some/url`.

I think it can be done with a **URL** record in the DNS server. But like mentioned [here] it can be done with HTTP server configuration as well. And ... that confused me.

AFAIK, a request starts with a DNS resolve, which give us the IP address of the server. From there one, HTTP traffic are IP based. So how does nginx/apache know the server name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no DNS `URL` record. If you refer to DNSimple product, it's actually a combination of `CNAME` (or `A`) record and simple HTTP server.

HTTP clients (browsers) send server's name in a header as a part of HTTP request.